# Trouble converting Excel file to .csv

Tags: excel, csv

My customer has a file they have used, for some time, to upload data to their application.  The field in the Oracle table is VARCHAR 50.   The field in the Excel spreadsheet they use is column width 50 and marked as General.  I change it to Text and save as .csv.  All the rows that have alphanumeric in the field save fine, but the ones that are all numbers convert to scientific notation.   I found something on here changing the format (Data > Text to columns) from General to Text.  Nothing makes the numbers convert as text like the other values in the field in this spreadsheet.  What can I do to ensure it does this every time?  They say it is the 1st time they've seen it...  I doubt that.  Still, I am on the hook to solve the problem.  I need to provide them with a solution so that when they send me this data, twice a year, to upload, it works correctly.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanx.

Comment: They are using the latest version of Excel, as am I.  Would changing to an older version help?

Comment: Tried to replicate the issue but was unable to get numbers to show in scientific notation.  Are these exceptionally long numbers?

Comment: The field they import into Oracle is VARCHAR 50.  The average size is between 35 and 40.

Comment: I had a related problem a while back.  Would a 50 character fixed length for these be acceptable using leading zeros?  For example the number 1 would appear as 49 zeros then the number 1.

Comment: I don't think so.  The numbers are actual serial numbers or some such.  They could be financial data, but I am not sure.  The bottom line, the customer wants them to import into their application as is and not scientific.  I suppose I could edit the .csv with Notepad, cut and paste the values from Excel to .csv, but there are over 3000 records to edit.  I'd rather find an automated method so it's not so time consuming.

Comment: If you write a macro that creates a CSV text file rather than using the save function you are golden as you can treat all of your cell values as strings.  I will check through my records, I think I have something easily adapted.

Comment: So the macro is listed as the answer below?  Thank you.  I haven't messed with macros for years.

Answer (score 0):

```
Public Sub WritetxtFiles()
    Const DELIMITER As String = ","
    Dim myRecord As Range
    Dim myField As Range
    Dim nFileNum As Long
    Dim sOut As String
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim holder As String
    Dim theDate As Date
    Dim formattedDate As String
    Dim dailyDirectory As String



    nFileNum = FreeFile


 theDate = Now
    formattedDate = Format(theDate, "yyyyMMdd")
    dailyDirectory = "C:\TEMP\" + formattedDate

    If Dir(dailyDirectory, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
    MkDir (dailyDirectory)

    Else
    End If




Sheets("orig.txt").Activate ' Adjust to match your sheet name

    Open dailyDirectory & "\orig.txt" For Output As #nFileNum ' Adjust to match your desired output
    counter = 1





    For Each myRecord In Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

        If Cells(counter, 1) <> "" Then


            With myRecord
                For Each myField In Range("A" & counter, "F" & counter)
                        sOut = sOut & DELIMITER & myField.Text
                Next myField

                Print #nFileNum, Mid(sOut, 2)
                sOut = Empty
            End With
        Else
        End If
        counter = counter + 1

    Next myRecord
    Close #nFileNum
end sub
```

This will create a comma delimited file in your C:\Temp[yyyymmdd]

Comment: Not really a date.  I would be changing a 35-40 number to a 35-40 character field.   I am assuming this would work with some tweaks for that?

Comment: It should work out of the box for that.  The date is only used in creation of the output directory and output text file.  You can remove it with a bit of work but it doesn't harm anything by being there.  It's a remanent of the larger part of code that this came from.

Comment: Fantastic!   I will work on it and post my results.  Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is for a gov't customer and they don't allow macros in their Excel files.  I was able to save as a 97-2003 workbook, then save as .csv.  If I open with Notepad instead of Excel, the .csv file appears correct.  If I open it with Excel, it converts.  Go figure.  Thanx for the help.  Wish I could have used it.

Comment: It makes sense that it converts in that way.  When you open the CSV in excel you have no formatting information stored so all cells start as general so the automatic sci-note rules apply.  The best thanks is an upvote ;)